# Replace under floor heating thermostat

Tags: electrical, thermostat

Trying to replace a Heatmiser Neo Stat Slimline V3 with a Meross MTS200.

This the configuration for the existing thermostat:

[image]

The Meross unit has an extra connector, not sure what to do with it (fairly certain I'm after the bottom of these two):

[image]

**Do I simply not wire anything into "NO"? and just use COM as A1 and NC as A2?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding your diagram, it's the other way around. Your existing thermostat has only a NO dry contact connection. Your new one has both NC and NO, so you ignore the NC contact. NO is short for Normally Open. A normally open contact is drawn like the one in your first diagram, with the angled line. COM+NO will match your A1+A2 behavior. COM+NC will work the other way around, and would be used for a system that expects that style of control.